# How to binaries image using ImageMagick?

Tags: ios, image-processing, imagemagick

I have got one image like this [image: Plate 1]

to only black and white colored image.

And I come across this [ImageMagick resource](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/iOS/)

1. Does this can be used to generate black and white image from the above given image?
2. Does it is good to use this one?
3. If it is good one then does there is any documentation or tutorial on "How to use?".

**UPDATE**

SO GOT THE BEST SOLUTION FROM @ale0xB's SUGGESTION.

No third party api is required for doing this as apple's COREIMAGE.FRAMEWORK is the best for doing what I want to do. It's filters are working like charm :)

Thanks for the suggestion :)

I use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMonochrome) image filter. And it is great in speed and provides great output :)

Comment: u meant greyscale image or B&W ?

Comment: only B&W no greyscale :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to use imageMagick instead of the standard Core Image to produce black and White images? I haven't used it before, but I doubt it's gonna give a much better performance than the native framework when it's just about creating a filter.

Since iOS 6 you have it really easy, have a look: [Core Image filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html), specially to CIColorMonochrome, which is the one you may be interested in.

If you're playing with images in your app, this is definitely worth checking: [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)

Comment: Hi will you please provide some tutorial or code how to apply the filters on image specially the CIColorMonochrome? Please :)

Comment: Hi, in the programming guide I referenced above you have plenty of code examples to achieve what you want, specially the "Using Core Image Filters" chapter. Plus, there's an example project on the topic called "PocketCoreImage". That should be more than enough to get started!

Comment: Thanks for reply But I figured out my solution :)